# c# How to calculate the sum of currently running textbox values

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

[image]

```
conn.Open();
int a;
int b;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(txt_required.Text, out a);
bool result2 = Int32.TryParse(txt_quantity.Text, out b);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_quantity.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_required.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_currentp.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_price.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_supplier.Text))
{

    MessageBox.Show("Please Input the Required Field", "Warning Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
else
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check your Quantity value", "Warning Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {


            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" INSERT into checkout (Name, Item, Quantity, Cost, Supplier)  values (@Name, @Item, @Quantity, @Cost, @Supplier)", conn);

            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt_customer.Text);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", listBox1.Text);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_required.Text);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", txt_currentp.Text);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", txt_supplier.Text);
            selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully");
            display();      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

This is my code for my add button. In the image above when i click the add button the value of the final price textbox should be displayed in the total sale and when i choose another item again and add that item( the final price of this item should be sum to the current total sale ) How can i do this ?
Logic Example: For example 1st item price is 100 so the total sale for now is 100 if i add another item( Price: 150) the total would be 250.  I want this logic but i don't know how.

Comment: So the value of Final Price and Total Sale will remain same?
You have to loop on grid records and do calc (Quantity * Cost) for each row and hold it in a variable and finally show on your desired text field.

Comment: do you already have code to get the text field and set initial value? just add code to set its value to; `quantity * price`.

Comment: @AamirNakhwa No sir, if i add an item the final price of that item will go to the total sale, if i add another item again the price of that will sum the currently value of the total sale. For example 1st item price is 100 so the total sale for now is 100 if i add another item( Price: 150) the total would be 250.

Comment: @JoelHarkes For example 1st item price is 100 so the total sale for now is 100 if i add another item( Price: 150) the total would be 250.  I want this logic but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AddButton_Click event

```
txtbxTotalsale.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtbxTotalsale.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtbxFinalPrize.Text)).Tostring();
```

Comment: Already solved sir. Thank you. I used For loop to sum the amount of my datagridview

Answer (score 1):

When you click-in into the checkout button then read the entire gridrow through looping and value assign back to the textbox.

```
 int totalsale=0;
    foreach(var item in mygrid.Rows)
    {
         totalsale += int.Parse(row.Cells["amount"]);
    }
    txtboxSale.Text= totalsale +"";
```

Comment: My pleasure. @Miracle

Comment: Dear @Miracle, the code was not useful ? because i lost my points. ;(